# Windows 7 not booting after GRUB installation

Tags: windows-7, grub, ubuntu-12.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 with GRUB. GRUB managed to pick the Windows 7 installation up fine however if I select the Windows 7 option at boot, it will go to a DOS screen with 2 characters, e (double-dotted) and a character that looks a bit like J (if these 2 characters mean anything). Windows 7 was working fine prior to installing Ubuntu and GRUB.

[EDIT]
boot-repair output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1699792/

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Linux, but I have another proposal. I would use the Windows 7 DVD-ROM to recover Windows. Then it will boot into Windows 7, but not Ubuntu. No problem, then I would use a free utility such as EasyBCD that allows you to manage the Windows boot loader a lot easier than Windows build-in BCDEdit. All you have to do is to add a new entry for Ubuntu and then point at the appropriate file (I don't remember which right now, just follow onscreen instructions). You can even rename each boot entry such as "Windows 7 Ultimate" and "Ubuntu 12.10" or whatever you like, and of course you can set the waiting time in seconds and the default OS. I would set Windows as default as I use it mostly and I guess about 4-5 sec is enough, so you don't have to wait too long for an unattended restart.

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks, I'll give that a try tomorrow when I'm back at home. I'll keep you updated if it works.